# Wordpress: Using the_post_thumbnail() for custom field image

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the custom field `photo` to upload an image. In the frontend I get its URL with this code:

```
$imgid=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'photo', true);
$img=wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgid);
$imgurl=$img[0];
```

Now I want to show it using the standard WP sizes (thumbnail, medium, ...) of  the_post_thumbnail().

I've tried some solutions that don't work:

```
the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('src' => $imgurl));
```

or

```
the_post_thumbnail('medium', $img);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the size as the second argument of [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), like so:

```
$imgid = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'photo', true);
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imgid, 'thumbnail' );
$imgurl = $img[0];
```